# Error XA1018 "Specified AndroidManifest file does not exist" en .NET MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, migration, android-manifest, maui

Estaba realizando una migración de un proyecto desde Xamarin Forms a .Net Maui y me aparece este error. Al parecer el error salta en el archivo **Xamarin.Android.Common.targets** y la ruta que me pone en la que deberia estar el AndroidManifest.xml seria en

**- [nombre_del_proyecto]\Android\AndroidManifest.xml**

pero en Maui se sitúa en

**- [nombre_del_proyecto]\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml**

He probado de todo con el comando **dotnet** y he revisado para que no haya ninguna referencia a Xamarin. Estoy usando **Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 bits) Version 17.3.6** con **Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8.09037**.

Comment: Reinicia visual studio y dime si funciona.

Comment: He probado a reiniciar , actualizar y/o downgradear el visual y nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final tras rehacer el proyecto de 0 paso por paso, resulta que el error surgía tras importar la librería **Uno.UI**. Al parecer no es compatible con la estructura de .NET Maui y ocasiona este error.